# How not to include Dots in plot_line_graph, Manim

Tags: python, animation, graph, manim

I have a problem, I need to plot a line graph with points and

```
plot_line_graph
```

method from Manim allows me to do that. But it also draws dots at each vertex of the line graph. How can I hide these dots?

I searched in Official Manim Documentation, but didn find any
thing useful...
[Line graph with this points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YATxf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [plot_line_graph documentation](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.graphing.coordinate_systems.Axes.html#manim.mobject.graphing.coordinate_systems.Axes.plot_line_graph) you just need to set the add_vertex_dots parameter to False.